# Why is there 16 possible functions when there are 2 inputs?

Tags: function, binary, boolean-operations

I'm really confused about this rn.
So I learned that there are four possible combinations of 2 inputs which are 00, 01, 10, 11.

Does that mean each input is considered one digit so it can be either 0 or 1?

From there, the textbook said there are 16 possible functions for 2 input because it's 2^4.

Why do you do 2^4? I just can't visualize how there can be 16 possible combinations.

Honestly, I'm not even sure how to describe this question. Could someone help me?

Comment: You've demonstrated the four combinations. Try doing the same with more inputs, making a list of all the possible combinations, and I think you can work this out for yourself. You can make it pretty simple - just add another input, so you have `00 00`, and work out the number of valid combinations for those.

Comment: Think about the definition of a function, not a named elementary function, but what does a function do in general.

Answer (score 0):

The 16 possible functions:

```
x y  F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 F10 F11 F12 F13 F14 F15 F16
0 0   0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
0 1   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
1 0   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
1 1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/generate-a-universal-binary-function-lookup-table

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a combinatorics question. Using luser droog's table as a reference, we know the output (column) is going to be a four-digit number, as there are four possible combinations of x and y (the ones you have listed in your question).

We can represent the output as [A][B][C][D], each letter's value corresponding to either 1 or 0. For example, A can assume either 1 and 0 as its values, meaning there are two possibilities. The same goes for B, C, and D.

We can write the number of possibilities for each letter in our representation as [ 2 ][ 2 ][ 2 ][ 2 ]. Having two possibilities for each entry, multiplication gives that 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16.

I cut it a bit short but hope it helps. Write me if you need anything.